# Define a global variable in Nunit SetUpFixture class

Tags: c#, nunit

Hi I have to use a variable in all my tests make with Nunit

```
SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
```

so I try to put this definition in the setup class:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public static class TestSetup
{
    public static SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();    
}
```

I use static class for ability to write:

```
IMyClass myClassExpected = (IMyClass)TestSetup.container.GetInstance(typeof(IMyClass), null);
```

but after running test I get this error: "TestSetup is an abstract class"

I simply don't understand where is the problem

Comment: Why don't you just have a base class that all the `TestFixture` classes inherit from? No need from for this static stuff then.

Comment: Because I simply found SetUpFixture as the place where put common code from Nunit doc... Inheriting from a base class in a great clean solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you not bother with having a static instance, and instead, use inheritance.

So create a base class, which includes your object:

```
public class BaseTestFixture
{
    public SimpleContainer Container { get { return new SimpleContainer(); } }
}
```

Have all your tests inherit from this:

```
public class GoogleTests : BaseTestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void GoToGoogle()
    {
        Container.GetInstance(.....);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your test fixture as static. Therefore NUnit cannot create an instance of it and gives you the error. Just change it to

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSetup
{
    ...
```

Comment: without static i can't use it my test. Arran solution works well

Comment: @gt.guybrush You do not need a class to be static to have static variables within it. The reference TestSetup.container will work just fine even if the class isn't static.

Comment: if not static i have to create an instance before use, and at this point i can simply create the instance of SimpleContainer. My idea is not to have to create a new instance in every method

Comment: @gt.guybrush, no you don't. You can access static members of a non-static class without creating an instance of that class. Please try it for yourself. Just remove the static from the class definition, recompile and re-run your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding this, but you can declare a class variable, and can do any assignments in the constructor. This is in the TestFixture class, not the SetUpFixture class.